# Files vanished from external hard drive for no reason. Anything I can do about this?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I had some data backed up onto an external hard drive, and it seemed fine. When I reopened the folder a few minutes later, there were only two files left instead of hundreds.

I can't think of anything  I was doing that might have caused this. I wasn't formatting or deleting anything, I wasn't doing anything to file systems, I wasn't doing anything that might have caused this.

The two files left are the two most recently edited.

*find* and *locate* commands don't show them anywhere else. Well, sorta: /home/user/.local/share/Trash/files/ contains all the directories, but they're all empty.

Is it hopeless? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What is your hard drive file system? is it NTFS?

Comment: Yeah, it's NTFS

Comment: Check the free space of the hard drive, does it seems that your data is still there? or it's look like disk is almost free? if the first one is the case, connect your hard disk to a windows machine an run a `chkdisk`.

Comment: That wouldn't be indicative. I use the hard drive for bulk storage, and the missing files are only txt files, take up very little room.

Comment: Anyway, if it's possible for you give windows `chkdisk` a shot ;)

Comment: Is the command simply *chkdsk*? Or are there flags?

Comment: [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2641432/check-your-hard-disk-for-errors-in-windows-7).

Comment: Thanks. They accidentally posted a picture in section 8 in German

Comment: You are welcome ;). typical Microsoft :)

Comment: Your drive may be mounted read-only. How did you mount the drive? Is this NTFS drive/partition the C: drive under Windows, or something else?

Comment: It mounted automatically when I plugged it in. Is it possible that the files are there, but hidden. (By the way, *ls* of that folder doesn't show the missing files.)